# Properly Escaping String Python

Tags: python, string, escaping

I'm trying to use selenium to locate a checkbox within an unordered list:

```
ul=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="TestTake"]/div[2]/div/div/ol/li[{}]/div[2]/ul'.format(num))

checkbox_id=ul.find_element_by_xpath("//[contains(text(),'{}')]".format(correct.replace("'","\'"))).get_attribute("for")
```

The problem with:

```
"//[contains(text(),'{}')]".format(correct.replace("'","\'"))).get_attribute("for"
```

occurs when `correct` is equal to `L'` or something that contains a quote.

How can I properly escape the single quote? I'm not sure if the correct will have a quote or not, so I need to be able to handle both cases, a double quote as well.

Also, this is the only approach because I only can get the id by the attribute `for` which I find by using its contents.

Comment: "'" and "\'" are exactly the same string. You need "'" and "\\'".

Comment: With that I end up with: The string '//*[contains(text(), 'L\'')]' is not a valid XPath expression. Can I escape use double quotes on the inside and escape them?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that string concatenation did the trick:

```
checkbox_id = ul.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),\"" + correct + "\")]").get_attribute("for")
```